# .NET HEX Colors too long for HTML

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Why is it that .NET uses hex codes like: #FFFAFAD2? Is there an easy way to get this to convert to HTML HEX (#FAFAD2) or shall I just substring the first three chars and then add the hash back on?

Comment: Where are the colors being defined, and how? Before you try to convert them to HTML equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pretty much got it, string replacement is going to be the easiest way. As a single line solution, you could use a regular expression, eg:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("#FFFAFAD2", "#..", "#")
```

Answer (score 6):

The first two are the alpha (transparency).